# Создать связь Несколько таблиц - к одной

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Хочу реализовать перевод на разные языки некоторых данных из разных таблиц.
Условно у меня есть таблица меню и таблица описания, я создаю две таблицы
1 с локалью:

```
public class Language : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Culture { get; set; }
}
```

И собственно с переводами

```
public class LanguageResource : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public Guid ParentUid { get; set; }

    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Где ParentUid это Uid в Menu который я бы хотел соотнести с этой таблицей и получать данные.

```
public class Menu : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public Guid Uid { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<LanguageResource> languageResources { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Priority { get; set; }
}
```

Но так же в ParentUid я бы хотел помещать Uid другой таблицы, что бы не создавать миллион таблиц с переводами под каждую.

Подскажите как это можно дальше реализовать? Не могу правильно настроить связь таблиц через CodeFirst

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я понял задачу, то можно использовать связь многие ко многим. Для этого создать промежуточную таблицу

```
public class LinkTable: BaseEntity
{
    public Menu menu{ get; set; } 
    public AnotherTable anotherTable{ get; set; } 
    public LanguageResource languageResource { get; set; } 
}
```

Т.е. вы получите линковочную таблицу сущностей для перевода с ресурсами перевода и сможете хранить меньше информации.

Comment: Интересное решение, спасибо

Comment: @Unnamed лучшее спасибо - принятый ответ.

Comment: @aepot решении интересное, но мне кажется можно сделать лучше. Хочу попробовать через Fluent и Uid соединить эти таблицы. Ну и может кто еще что посоветует, так как в этом решении я вижу явный недостаток что из меню я буду зачем то видеть еще другую таблицу